# Django Language Selector in local and native language

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

I have a django website I am adding translations to with a language selector that lists the available languages in the user's language.  I would like to have the dropdown include the native spelling also.

Currently it looks like this:
English
Dutch
Simplified Chinese

When I switch to Chinese it looks like:
英语
荷兰语
简体中文

I am trying to make it look like:
English/English
Dutch/Nederlands
Simplified Chinese/简体中文

settings.py includes:

```
ugettext = lambda s: s  
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('nl', ugettext('Dutch')),
    ('zh-cn', ugettext('Simplified Chinese')),
)
```

base.html:

```
    {% load i18n %}
    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
    <form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="language">
          {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
            <option value="{{ lang.0 }}">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
```

My thought was to add another item to LANGUAGES that is the native language, like:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English'), 'English'),
    ('nl', ugettext('Dutch'), 'Nederlands'),
    ('zh-ch', ugettext('Simplified Chinese'), '简体中文'),)
```

But Django seems to expect a 2 item tuple for LANGUAGES.  Any other ideas?

**EDIT per Alexander's comment:**
I thought that might be a simpler solution, but after changing the code:

```
        <form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
        <select name="language">
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option value="nl">Dutch\Nederlands</option>
            <option value="ru">Russian\Русский</option>
            <option value="zh-cn">Simplified Chinese-简体中文</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
```

The Russian and Chinese scripts are showing up as question marks - Russian\???????, Chinese-????

I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`
 in the html, other Russian and Chinese text (outside of this form) appears fine.

Comment: We didn't bother ourselves with such a problem: hardcoded one part in template and that's all.

Comment: You would have to switch/set languages and enumerate through all of them to generate all possible native translations of each language name. Its far easier to just embed a predefined dict of names with native spelling for each language you want and pass it to the template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en',    '{}/{}'.format(ugettext('English'), 'English')),
    ('nl',    '{}/{}'.format(ugettext('Dutch'), 'Nederlands')),
    ('zh-cn', '{}/{}'.format(ugettext('Simplified Chinese'), '简体中文')),
)
```

Then you can use this in your templates:

```
{% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
    <option value="{{ lang.0 }}">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That codes gives me a UnicodeDecodeError at /
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128) when the template calls {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}.   If I change to u'简体中文' then I get a UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128) when importing settings.py

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format comments well...  I had to set the encoding of settings.py to utf-8, and some other adjustments.  This language encoding has a lot of bases to cover to get working well!

Comment: you don't need to use {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}. If you haven't changed `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, then `{{ LANGUAGES }}` is already available to your templates by default. {% get_available_languages %} causes the UnicodeDecodeError you are getting.

Comment: Just tried and you are correct!  The only difference I see is without the **get_available_languages** LANGUAGES does not translate. So the original example always shows English, or the English/Native when I add your **.format(ugettext...** code.  But this does answer my original question.  I see I have more to learn getting my head around translations.  Thank you.

Comment: with django1.7 + python3 i can not use format in tuple?

Answer (score 1):

Taking Alexander's suggestion, I was able to get the code in the edit above to work properly.  I did not have the `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />`
 line within the 'head' area, which is required, and that was giving me the ???? where the Chinese characters should have been.

After seeing it in action, I may have 2 language selectors, one that gets translated into the current language, and another with the English/Native characters if it isn't too busy.

I also will put the language list in a module and pass it to the template similar to getting the LANGUAGES.